On Projective bundle
Let $m,n >1$. Then the biprojective space $\mathbb P^m \times \mathbb P^n$ can be thought of as projective  bundle corresponding to $m+1$ copies of $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^n}(1)$ on $\mathbb P^n$.
Now let us consider the projective  bundle corresponding to $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^n}(a) \oplus \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^n}(b)$ for some integers $a, b >0$ over $\mathbb P^n$. Is there an analogous description of the same?

First, $m + 1$ copies, not $m$. Second, what exactly do you want?

@Sasha, thanks. Edited the question now. My question is that can we have a similar description like $\mathbb P^n$ times some other variety (or is there no analogous such description?)

If $a$ and $b$ are different then your projective bundle is not a product of $\mathbb P^n$ with another variety.

@Lazzaro Campeotti, Thanks. What if $a=b \neq 1$?

The result of a projectivization does not change if you twist your vector bundle, so $$\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{O}(a) \oplus \mathcal{O}(b)) \cong \mathbb{P}(\mathcal{O}(a+k) \oplus \mathcal{O}(b+k))$$ for any $k$.

@Sasha, Does this mean that for example for $a \neq b$, the projective bundles say $\mathbb P(\mathcal O(a) \oplus \mathcal O(a) \oplus \mathcal O(b))$  or for $a \neq b \neq c$, he projective bundles say $\mathbb P(\mathcal O(a) \oplus \mathcal O(b) \oplus \mathcal O(c))$ over $\mathbb P^2$ has no easy alternative description?

There are many descriptions, but the natural one, the projective bundle description, is usually the most convenient. What does not satisfy you in that description?

@Sasha, I'm ok with the the natural projective bundle description. I just wanted to know in the equal case we have, $\mathbb P(\mathcal O(a) \oplus \mathcal O(a) \oplus \mathcal O(a)) \cong \mathbb P^2 \times \mathbb P^2$, what happens in the non-equal cases. May be they also have description but not as straightforward as biprojective spaces?

What exactly do you mean by "they also also have descriptions"? The projective bundle description is a description. What else do you want?
